# how can I make a holiday indicator in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

```
DataOrigin['isholiday'] = DataOrigin['arrival'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='2016-06-10'or'2016-06-09'or '2016-06-11'else 0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI4eH.png)

Please click on the image first,  above is my code
My description is including in the picture, aprreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check if the values are in a given subset of data.

```
DataOrigin['isholiday'] = DataOrigin['arrival'].isin(['2016-06-10', '2016-06-09', '2016-06-11'])
```

If you really want ones and zeroes instead of True/False, just append `.astype(int)` to the statement above.  True/False should evaluate the same as 1/0, so it is really down to preference or your specific use case.

Comment: Add `.astype(int)` so that it is 1 or 0 (based on what OP seemed to be trying to do)

Comment: Yes, I considered that, but T/F is generally the same.